# MySql IEEE floating point NaN, PositiveInfinity, NegativeInfinity

Tags: mysql, nan, ieee-754, infinity

I have looked at many questions regarding this problem, but I have not found a solution. Hopefully this is not a duplicate question.

## Problem

If I do any of:

```
INSERT INTO `Numbers`(`Number`) VALUES ('NaN')
INSERT INTO `Numbers`(`Number`) VALUES ('Inf')
INSERT INTO `Numbers`(`Number`) VALUES ('+Inf')
```

I get 0.0 inserted in the table. Sometimes I get:

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'Number'
```

I have also tried different casing and spelling, all with the same effect.

I have even tried:

```
INSERT INTO `Numbers`(`Number`) VALUES ('1111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
```

How do I insert a NaN floating point number into a MySql table?

If it really isn't possible then what is the reasoning? (Maybe I am using the incorrect version of MySql?)

## Using NULL as NaN

The tables where I am actually using this I don't want to allow NULL values in those columns. So I don't like the idea of replacing NaN with NULL somewhere in the ORM layer

Comment: You most likely don't get an error because your session is configured with a legacy SQL_MODE. And, sorry, you can only store finite numbers.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any idea why it is like that? I am assuming that the MySql team didn't just forget about it. They must have made the choice for some reason?

Comment: Quoting [Raymond Chen](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/seanearp/2007/04/12/why-doesnt-this-feature-exist/): *The answer to “Why doesn’t this feature exist?” is usually “By default features don’t exist. Somebody has to implement them.”

It’s not like every feature you can think of comes out of your brain fully tested and implemented, and then some PM somewhere files a bug to have your feature removed.  Features start out nonexistent and somebody has to make them happen.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get an overall idea of how MySQL manipulates numbers you can read the following chapters:

- [Numeric Type Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html) and [Numeric Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html), including [Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html)
- [Number Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/number-literals.html)
- [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)

The last article mentions this:

> The server includes `dtoa`, a conversion library that provides the
>   basis for improved conversion between string or `DECIMAL` values and
>   approximate-value (`FLOAT`/`DOUBLE`) numbers
>
> [...]
>
> The dtoa library provides conversions with the following properties. `D`
>   represents a value with a `DECIMAL` or string representation, and `F`
>   represents a floating-point number in native binary (IEEE) format.
>
> [...]
>
> conversions are lossless unless `F` is `-inf`, `+inf`, or `NaN`. The latter
>   values are not supported because the SQL standard defines them as
>   invalid values for `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.

In short:

- The SQL standard explicitly bans those values
- MySQL complies with the standard in that aspect