# Inserting NaN value into MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have some data that contains NULLs, floats and the occasional Nan. I'm trying to insert this data into a MySQL database using python and MySqldb.

Here's the insert statement:

```
for row in zip(currents, voltages):
        row = [id] + list(row)
        for item in row:
            sql_insert = ('INSERT INTO result(id, current, voltage)'
                            'VALUES(%s, "%s")')
            cursor.execute(sql_insert, row)
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE langmuir_result (result_id INT auto_increment, 
                              id INT, 
                              current FLOAT,
                              voltage FLOAT,
                              PRIMARY KEY (result_id));
```

When I try to insert NaN into the table I get this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.DataError: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'current' at row 1")
```

I want to insert the NaN values into the database as a float or a number, not a string or NULL. I've tried having the type of the column be FLOAT and DECIMAL but get the same error. How can I do this without making it a string or NULL? Is that possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible to store a NaN value in a FLOAT type columns in Mysql. Values allowed are only NULL or a number. You may solve it using some value that you don't use for NaN (maybe negatives, a big/low value)

Comment: If you know the size of the float you are trying to store, a NaN is specifically encoded in IEEE float numbers. "IEEE 754 NaNs are represented with the exponent field filled with ones (like infinity values), and some non-zero number in the significand (to make them distinct from infinity values)"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point

Comment: @nacho perfect, thanks! If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN I unfortunately don't know the size, it's generated from a sensor

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936403/mysql-ieee-floating-point-nan-positiveinfinity-negativeinfinity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to store a NaN value in a FLOAT type columns in Mysql. Values allowed are only NULL or a number. You may solve it using some value that you don't use for NaN (maybe negatives, a big/low value)

Comment: And there is no such thing as *NaN* value in MySQL. That is strictly a Python numpy/pandas entity.

Comment: This isn't correct. NaN is part of the IEEE standard and NOT a Python/numpy/pandas entity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your `NaN` to `None` since MySQL understands `None` and in the UI you'll see `NULL`

Comment: Perfect for Python

Answer (score -2):

You may use pandas package isna function:

```
    import pandas as pd # use pandas package

    if pd.isna(row[column]):
          values_data.append(None)
        else:
          values_data.append(row[column])
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The "Post Answer" button should be used only for complete answers to the question.