# Uneven column count in MySQL INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, insert, sql-insert

I'm trying to execute 2 pretty stereotypical MySQL Statements: create table, and insert into table values(...). While they both are syntactically valid individually, running the insert statement after the create table command produces the following error:

`mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

My create table command is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE trackman (
    PitchNo INT,
    `Date` DATETIME,
    `Time` TIME,
    PAofInning INT,
    PitchofPA INT,
    Pitcher VARCHAR(255),
    PitcherId INT,
    PitcherThrows VARCHAR(255),
    PitcherTeam VARCHAR(255),
    Batter VARCHAR(255),
    BatterId INT,
    BatterSide VARCHAR(255),
    BatterTeam VARCHAR(255),
    PitcherSet VARCHAR(255),
    Inning INT,
    Top_Bottom INT,
    Outs INT,
    Balls INT,
    Strikes INT,
    TaggedPitchType VARCHAR(255),
    AutoPitchType VARCHAR(255),
    PitchCall VARCHAR(255),
    KorBB VARCHAR(255),
    TaggedHitType VARCHAR(255),
    PlayResult VARCHAR(255),
    OutsOnPlay INT,
    RunsScored INT,
    Notes VARCHAR(255),
    RelSpeed VARCHAR(255),
    VertRelAngle VARCHAR(255),
    HorzRelAngle VARCHAR(255),
    SpinRate VARCHAR(255),
    SpinAxis VARCHAR(255),
    Tilt TIME,
    RelHeight FLOAT,
    RelSide FLOAT,
    Extension FLOAT,
    VertBreak FLOAT,
    InducedVertBreak FLOAT,
    HorzBreak FLOAT,
    PlateLocHeight FLOAT,
    PlateLocSide FLOAT,
    ZoneSpeed FLOAT,
    VertApprAngle FLOAT,
    HorzApprAngle FLOAT,
    ZoneTime FLOAT,
    ExitSpeed FLOAT,
    Angle FLOAT,
    Direction FLOAT,
    HitSpinRate FLOAT,
    PositionAt110X FLOAT,
    PositionAt110Y FLOAT,
    PositionAt110Z FLOAT,
    Distance FLOAT,
    LastTrackedDistance FLOAT,
    Bearing FLOAT,
    HangTime FLOAT,
    pfxx FLOAT,
    pfxz FLOAT,
    x0 FLOAT,
    y0 FLOAT,
    z0 FLOAT,
    vx0 FLOAT,
    vy0 FLOAT,
    vz0 FLOAT,
    ax0 FLOAT,
    ay0 FLOAT,
    az0 FLOAT,
    HomeTeam VARCHAR(255),
    AwayTeam VARCHAR(255),
    Stadium VARCHAR(255),
    Level VARCHAR(255),
    League VARCHAR(255),
    GameID VARCHAR(255),
    PitchUID VARCHAR(255),
    EffectiveVelo FLOAT,
    MaxHeight FLOAT,
    MeasuredDuration FLOAT,
    SpeedDrop FLOAT,
    PitchLastMeasuredX FLOAT,
    PitchLastMeasuredY FLOAT,
    PitchLastMeasuredZ FLOAT,
    ContactPositionX FLOAT,
    ContactPositionY FLOAT,
    ContactPositionZ FLOAT,
    GameUID VARCHAR(255),
    UTCDate DATE,
    UTCTime TIME,
    LocalDateTime DATETIME,
    UTCDateTime DATETIME,
    AutoHitType VARCHAR(255),
    System_ VARCHAR(255),
    HomeTeamForeignID VARCHAR(255),
    AwayTeamForeignID VARCHAR(255),
    GameForeignID VARCHAR(255),
    Catcher VARCHAR(255),
    CatcherId VARCHAR(255),
    CatcherThrows VARCHAR(255),
    CatcherTeam VARCHAR(255),
    PlayID VARCHAR(255),
    PitchTrajectoryXc0 FLOAT,
    PitchTrajectoryXc1 FLOAT,
    PitchTrajectoryXc2 FLOAT,
    PitchTrajectoryYc0 FLOAT,
    PitchTrajectoryYc1 FLOAT,
    PitchTrajectoryYc2 FLOAT,
    PitchTrajectoryZc0 FLOAT,
    PitchTrajectoryZc1 FLOAT,
    PitchTrajectoryZc2 FLOAT,
    HitSpinAxis FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc0 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc1 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc2 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc3 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc4 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc5 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc6 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc7 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryXc8 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc0 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc1 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc2 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc3 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc4 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc5 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc6 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc7 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryYc8 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc0 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc1 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc2 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc3 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc4 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc5 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc6 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc7 FLOAT,
    HitTrajectoryZc8 FLOAT,
    ThrowSpeed FLOAT,
    PopTime FLOAT,
    ExchangeTime FLOAT,
    TimeToBase FLOAT,
    CatchPositionX FLOAT,
    CatchPositionY FLOAT,
    CatchPositionZ FLOAT,
    ThrowPositionX FLOAT,
    ThrowPositionY FLOAT,
    ThrowPositionZ FLOAT,
    BasePositionX FLOAT,
    BasePositionY FLOAT,
    BasePositionZ FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryXc0 FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryXc1 FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryXc2 FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryYc0 FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryYc1 FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryYc2 FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryZc0 FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryZc1 FLOAT,
    ThrowTrajectoryZc2 FLOAT,
    PitchReleaseConfidence VARCHAR(255),
    PitchLocationConfidence VARCHAR(255),
    PitchMovementConfidence VARCHAR(255),
    HitLaunchConfidence VARCHAR(255),
    HitLandingConfidence VARCHAR(255),
    CatcherThrowCatchConfidence VARCHAR(255),
    CatcherThrowReleaseConfidence VARCHAR(255),
    CatcherThrowLocationConfidence VARCHAR(255)
)
```

After executing that, MySQL returns no errors and seems to deem everything syntactically valid. I then execute the following sample insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO trackman (
            PitchNo,
            `Date`,
            `Time`,
            PAofInning,
            PitchofPA,
            Pitcher,
            PitcherId,
            PitcherThrows,
            PitcherTeam,
            Batter,
            BatterId,
            BatterSide,
            BatterTeam,
            PitcherSet,
            Inning,
            Top_Bottom,
            Outs,
            Balls,
            Strikes,
            TaggedPitchType,
            AutoPitchType,
            PitchCall,
            KorBB,
            TaggedHitType,
            PlayResult,
            OutsOnPlay,
            RunsScored,
            Notes,
            RelSpeed,
            VertRelAngle,
            HorzRelAngle,
            SpinRate,
            SpinAxis,
            Tilt,
            RelHeight,
            RelSide,
            Extension,
            VertBreak,
            InducedVertBreak,
            HorzBreak,
            PlateLocHeight,
            PlateLocSide,
            ZoneSpeed,
            VertApprAngle,
            HorzApprAngle,
            ZoneTime,
            ExitSpeed,
            Angle,
            Direction,
            HitSpinRate,
            PositionAt110X,
            PositionAt110Y,
            PositionAt110Z,
            Distance,
            LastTrackedDistance,
            Bearing,
            HangTime,
            pfxx,
            pfxz,
            x0,
            y0,
            z0,
            vx0,
            vy0,
            vz0,
            ax0,
            ay0,
            az0,
            HomeTeam,
            AwayTeam,
            Stadium,
            Level,
            League,
            GameID,
            PitchUID,
            EffectiveVelo,
            MaxHeight,
            MeasuredDuration,
            SpeedDrop,
            PitchLastMeasuredX,
            PitchLastMeasuredY,
            PitchLastMeasuredZ,
            ContactPositionX,
            ContactPositionY,
            ContactPositionZ,
            GameUID,
            UTCDate,
            UTCTime,
            LocalDateTime,
            UTCDateTime,
            AutoHitType,
            System_,
            HomeTeamForeignID,
            AwayTeamForeignID,
            GameForeignID,
            Catcher,
            CatcherId,
            CatcherThrows,
            CatcherTeam,
            PlayID,
            PitchTrajectoryXc0,
            PitchTrajectoryXc1,
            PitchTrajectoryXc2,
            PitchTrajectoryYc0,
            PitchTrajectoryYc1,
            PitchTrajectoryYc2,
            PitchTrajectoryZc0,
            PitchTrajectoryZc1,
            PitchTrajectoryZc2,
            HitSpinAxis,
            HitTrajectoryXc0,
            HitTrajectoryXc1,
            HitTrajectoryXc2,
            HitTrajectoryXc3,
            HitTrajectoryXc4,
            HitTrajectoryXc5,
            HitTrajectoryXc6,
            HitTrajectoryXc7,
            HitTrajectoryXc8,
            HitTrajectoryYc0,
            HitTrajectoryYc1,
            HitTrajectoryYc2,
            HitTrajectoryYc3,
            HitTrajectoryYc4,
            HitTrajectoryYc5,
            HitTrajectoryYc6,
            HitTrajectoryYc7,
            HitTrajectoryYc8,
            HitTrajectoryZc0,
            HitTrajectoryZc1,
            HitTrajectoryZc2,
            HitTrajectoryZc3,
            HitTrajectoryZc4,
            HitTrajectoryZc5,
            HitTrajectoryZc6,
            HitTrajectoryZc7,
            HitTrajectoryZc8,
            ThrowSpeed,
            PopTime,
            ExchangeTime,
            TimeToBase,
            CatchPositionX,
            CatchPositionY,
            CatchPositionZ,
            ThrowPositionX,
            ThrowPositionY,
            ThrowPositionZ,
            BasePositionX,
            BasePositionY,
            BasePositionZ,
            ThrowTrajectoryXc0,
            ThrowTrajectoryXc1,
            ThrowTrajectoryXc2,
            ThrowTrajectoryYc0,
            ThrowTrajectoryYc1,
            ThrowTrajectoryYc2,
            ThrowTrajectoryZc0,
            ThrowTrajectoryZc1,
            ThrowTrajectoryZc2,
            PitchReleaseConfidence,
            PitchLocationConfidence,
            PitchMovementConfidence,
            HitLaunchConfidence,
            HitLandingConfidence,
            CatcherThrowCatchConfidence,
            CatcherThrowReleaseConfidence,
            CatcherThrowLocationConfidence
        ) VALUES (
            1,
            '2021-10-17 00:00:00',
            '14:00:35.170000',
            1,
            1,
            Molsky, Tommy,
            1000113075,
            'Right',
            PSU_PRA,
            Gerlott, Billy,
            1000113070,
            'Right',
            PSU_PRA,
            Undefined,
            1,
            Top,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            Fastball,
            Four-Seam,
            BallCalled,
            Undefined,
            Undefined,
            Undefined,
            0,
            0,
            nan,
            91.31813,
            -1.875088,
            -0.537669,
            2115.387638,
            221.018375,
            '01:15:00',
            6.22382,
            1.52511,
            4.76868,
            -17.50584,
            17.54001,
            14.25583,
            2.98657,
            2.20333,
            83.24518,
            -5.130651,
            1.968691,
            0.426079,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            -7.1117,
            9.4691,
            -1.48433,
            50.0,
            6.02144,
            0.52971,
            -132.33521,
            -4.97121,
            -12.59033,
            28.68101,
            -15.41025,
            PSU_PRA,
            PSU_PRA,
            LubranoPark,
            TeamExclusive,
            Team,
            20211017-LubranoPark-Private-1,
            20ceac50-2f74-11ec-a5be-95556a47fac4,
            88.46359,
            nan,
            nan,
            8.07295,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            37a45891-f7a3-4baa-a457-be34e679de3e,
            '2021-10-17 00:00:00',
            '18:00:35.170000',
            '2021-10-17 14:00:35',
            '2021-10-17 18:00:35',
            nan,
            v3,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            Spiegel, Josh,
            1000013427,
            'Right',
            PSU_PRA,
            6172a24f-d478-441b-83a7-96188ee30278,
            55.7273,
            -133.57072,
            14.3405,
            6.22129,
            -4.30737,
            -7.70512,
            -1.51883,
            1.07207,
            -6.29517,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            High,
            High,
            High,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan,
            nan
        );
```

I've checked 5+ times to be absolutely certain that the columns all match, and I'm pretty positive they do. I suppose my question has more to do with what I don't know? Does MySQL create its own columns when being instantiated that aren't viewable? Is there a syntax error I've missed? I'm not sure what's going on here.

I've run each statement through some online tools to make sure they're not syntactically invalid, but every tool I've used says that the columns are of different lengths? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `NaN` as float values. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756557/inserting-nan-value-into-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

You forget that **all non-numeric literals must be enclosed with quote chars**.

For example, the value

```
Molsky, Tommy,
```

is treated not as one string value but as 2 separate columns with the names `Molsky` and `Tommy`. This line must look loke

```
'Molsky, Tommy',
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'll go ahead and fix that right away. Is there anything to be said for all the nan values at the bottom (should I convert to NULL) or does MySQL know how to handle those?

Comment: @SuaveXZ `nan` value is unknown to MySQL. Use NULL or some pre-defined hardcoded constant value instead.